# grant procedure

Tags: db2, db2-luw

A batch process run by user U drops and creates a work table T. Simplified setup:

rights for user U

```
db2 grant dataaccess on database to user U
db2 grant all on table T to user U
db2 transfer ownership of table T to user U
```

Since the code is called from several places I thought it would be nice to drop and create the table from a procedure P, to avoid that different code creates different looks for the table.

```
db2 -td@ -f "create procedure P()
   LANGUAGE SQL
   BEGIN
       BEGIN
           -- do nothing if drop table fails
           DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42704'
           BEGIN
           END;
           execute immediate 'drop table T';
       END;
       execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE T (x int)';
END @"
```

However, when user U calls this procedure it fails with:

```
db2 "call P()"
SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the 
required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization 
ID: "U". Operation: "CREATE TABLE". Object: T SQLSTATE=42501
```

Is it possible to grant rights to user U (beside dbadm or other nuclear options :) so that it can successfully execute procedure P?

Comment: Firstly, in your example you rely on implicit schema resolution, which might be a factor. Secondly, there are specific privileges that U needs to have in order to create a table in a particular schema and tablespace, which you don't grant. U's and the other user (grantor) membership in various groups and roles might also affect the scenario.

Comment: I think you nailed it. DROP is ok since U owns the table, but create is not ok since U does not have CREATIN on schema. I think I will move the table out to another schema. If you add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add an answer then. The comment by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) made me realize that U is able to drop T since U owns T. But as soon as T is dropped, U can not recreate it since `CREATIN` is not granted to U in the schema.

The solution is to create a schema S, GRANT CREATIN/DROPIN ON S to user U, then change the schema of T to S.

Comment: It's still interesting that you don't see the problem when running the same commands outside the routine. Does the PUBLIC group have permissions on the schema and tablespace? Or some other group or role that U belongs to? If so, your problem might be caused by some funny application of `DYNAMICRULES` inside the routine.

Comment: I'm not sure why that worked. When I tried, later on, I could not repeat the success, instead got the same error. The most likely cause is that I had terminals open on several desktops, and accidentally switched to a terminal connected as another user. Sorry for the confusion this caused.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase the question